# shortestpath with OrientDB very slow

Tags: orientdb, shortest-path, orientdb2.2

With OrientDB and Java I have a program with this query to calculate the shortest path to 300000 nodes for the all pairs of nodes but the program is very slow someone can help me.

```
String query = "select expand(shortestPath("+source.getId()+","+dest.getId()+",'OUT'))";
```

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?

Comment: Hi @MichelaBonizzi Orientdb 2.2.10

Comment: What is your configuration (memory)?

Comment: Processor: i7 2.60 GHz, 16 GB Ram, 64-bit Operating System

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, I was talking about orientdb memory configuration

Comment: I do not know how to set the orientdb memory configuration can you help me please :(

Comment: When you start the server in the initials lines you should see the orientdb configuration e.s. DISKCACHE...., then post the parameters

Comment: Look at: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Performance-Tuning.html#server-and-embedded-settings